Why does the compiler optimize `g` to always return true, even though `i == INT_MAX` avoids undefined behavior?
In this example from CppCon:
bool f(int i) { return i + 1 > i; }

bool g(int i) {
  if (i == INT_MAX) return false;
  else return f(i);
}

The compiler optimizes f to always return true because signed integer overflow is undefined behavior (UB). However, I don't understand why it would optimize g to always return true, even when i == INT_MAX.
For i == INT_MAX, no overflow occurs in g, so UB should never happen. Why does the compiler still change the behavior of g?
I tried this on Compiler Explorer with -O3 on x86-64 Clang 19.1.0, and this was the output:
f(int):
        mov     al, 1
        ret

g(int):
        cmp     edi, 2147483647
        setne   al
        ret

As you can see, it doesn't optimize g to always return true — it properly checks for i == INT_MAX. Was the information presented in the video incorrect?
Here's a quote from the video explaining the behavior:

In particular it means when you call f, integer overflow does not happen, so i != INT_MAX. It will then, under that assumption, eliminate what is basically that code, because i != INT_MAX. So the first line of g is that code — it will never happen.

Here’s the link to the video for reference.

Where does it optimize g to always return true? You can clearly see a condition in gs assembly code.

SO questions should not be dependent on external links.  Please edit the question to include a transcription of the claims you're asking about.  Not only will that clarify, it  will also preserve the question's utility in the event that the video is taken down or moved.

Are you asking about c or c++? they're separate languages especially in regards to what is and isn't undefined behaviour

I believe you are correct that this example is wrong, for the reason that you stated. Some of the comments to the video also say that.

The compiler (in particular the optimizer) is allowed to assume (and indeed, presumes) that UB does not happen.  The clever optimizer will note that i can not be INT_MAX in the code provided, because if it were then f would result in UB... therefore the first arm in the g function will never happen, and the g function can only ever return true.  The compiler you selected to check does not perform that clever optimization.

@Eljay but if i == INT_MAX, then f is not called, so it cannot assume i != INT_MAX

@chrysante • You'll need to watch the video where Fedor Pikus is explaining the viral nature of UB.  (He also explains that he is not aware of any compiler that performs this particular optimization.  Today.  But they could, as per the standard.)  Or read Raymond Chen's blog post on UB can result in time travel.

@Eljay I'm aware of the "time travel" UB, but as the blog post says: This new line introduces a bug: It dereferences the pointer p without checking if it is null. The compiler can make assumptions based on UB in all program points that are post-dominated by the UB. Here it's a different case however, because the call to f doesn't post-dominate the i == INT_MAX check, i.e., an invocation of the program that performs the check does not necessarily call f. If that were the case, then the compiler could elide the check.

@chrysante • I chatted with Fedor.  His reasoning is that the optimizer can do a (pseudo-code) conversion to "return !(if (i < INT_MAX) return false; else return !f(i));" and optimize that to "return true;" because the else clause domain is i < INT_MAX (otherwise UB) which is already covered in the if.  No compilers he has tested with does this (potential) optimization.

@Eljay In the code snippet you provide, you negated the branch condition but did not switch the branch arms. Now the program can make a call to f(INT_MAX)  that the original program did not make. A valid transformation akin to yours would be return !(if (i < INT_MAX) return !f(i); else return true;);, but this doesn't invoke UB.

The presenter got it wrong. The compiler could assume i != INT_MAX if f was called unconditionally, but because g explicitly checks for the one input that would make f produce UB, and in that case doesn't make the call, this is fine.
I think what he means is that in this case:
bool f(int i) { return i + 1 > i; }

int global;

bool g(int i) {
  if (i == INT_MAX) 
      global = 42;
  return f(i);
}

a conforming compiler could delete the first part of the function. But compilers don't do this in practice, because it produces all sorts of surprising behaviour, that programmers don't want:
// Infinite loop
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    // Overflows if i >= 3, thus the compiler may assume i < 3 
    // and replace the i < 4 check with true
    std::cout << i * 1'000'000'000 << std::endl;
}


Infinite loop, why?

@ABu 3 * 1'000'000'000 overflows, i.e. UB, so the compiler can assume i < 3, because UB doesn't happen, and then it can replace i < 5 with true

@chrysante I've seen this just last week with gcc 12, albeit it usually makes infinite loop when exactly last iteration is UB (e.g. index out of array bound, suddenly there is a jmp in assembler instead of jle), otherwise it may unwind the loop and assembler code would contain less iterations.

@ABu: Speaking of infinite loops, clang in both C and C++ modes will sometimes treat side-effect-free loops as an invitation to arbitrarily corrupt memory in cases where they would fail to terminate, and gcc will do likewise in C++ mode though so far as I can tell doesn't presently do so in C mode.
